# How do you debug libpcap code as a normal user on OS X with Xcode?

Tags: c, macos, unix, xcode4, libpcap

I Have written following code using libpcap in xCode

```
#include<pcap.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#define MAXBYTES2CAPTURE 2048


void processPacket(u_char *arg,const struct pcap_pkthdr* pkthdr,const u_char* packet){
    int i=0,*counter=(int*)arg;
    printf("Packet Count:%d\n",++(*counter));
    printf("Recived Packet Size:%d\n",pkthdr->len);
    printf("Payload:\n");
    for(i=0;i<pkthdr->len;i++){
        if(isprint(packet[i]))
           printf("%c",packet[i]);
        else
            printf(". ");
        if((i%16==0&&i!=0)||i==pkthdr->len-1)
            printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int count=0;
    pcap_t *descr=NULL;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    memset(errbuf,0,PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE);
    descr=pcap_open_live("en1", MAXBYTES2CAPTURE, 1, 512, errbuf);
    if(descr!=NULL)
        pcap_loop(descr, -1, processPacket,(u_char*)&count);
    else
        printf("ERROR");


        return 0;
}
```

Now While running from xCode 4.4 it Displays "ERROR"
but when I go to the product directory and run like this in terminal :

```
sudo ./TCP_packet
password:********
```

It runs fine
I have already used setuid(0),But still not working in xCode!!!
So,How can I Run this program as root in xCode, is there some setting that I have to do in xCode
xCode ver:4.4
OSX:10.7 Lion
thank U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why people are saying to chmod the `/dev/bpf*` files. Just add yourself to the `access_bpf` group so your user account can access the packet filter devices.

Go to `Apple menu > System Preferences... > Users & Groups`, unlock the panel if needed, click the `+`, select `Group` from the drop-down, name the group `access_bpf`, and create it. Then expand `Groups` and make sure your user account is added to it.

Works for me. I don't need to use `sudo` to capture packets. (or `chmod` every boot)

Comment: That only works if you've installed Wireshark, which creates that group - *and* adds the user who installed Wireshark to it, changes the group owner of the BPF devices to it, and installs a StartupItem to change the group owner of the BPF devices on a reboot.  If you haven't installed Wireshark, or created the `access_bpf` group yourself, that group won't exist.

Comment: @Guy, interesting, thanks. So short answer: install Wireshark and don't worry about it? ;-)

Comment: Installing a recent version of Wireshark (which I assume you've already done) on OS X will install all the mechanisms necessary to support using BPF (whether through libpcap or something else) without being root (it does so in order to make it possible for Wireshark to capture without running as root), and, yes, it's probably the easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the app setuid, owned by root **after** building.

If you want to make the program work you need to do:

```
chown root:wheel TCP_packet
chmod u+s TCP_packet
```

This will allow it to run with root privileges, and thus access the packet capture device.

If you've installed wireshark, it should have added your user account to an `access_bpf` group, which permits access to the `/dev/bpf*` devices, which is what you need to perform packet capture.

prior to this helper, I used to do: `sudo chgrp admin /dev/bpf*; sudo chmod g+r /dev/bpf*`, which allowed access to the packet capture device until next reboot

Answer (score 0):

setuid only works on a system(), fork() or exec() calls, so this won't help you

what you can do is `chmod u+s TCP_packet` as the root user, this will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Or, because you are debugging and want this done as root; just simply launch Xcode as root.

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/
sudo ./Xcode
```

Navigate to your project and you are good to go.

Enjoy.

~moses